# Is there any good reason to write things "backwards", e.g.: if ("some_text" == var_name)?

Tags: c#, coding-style

I was doing a project in groups of 4 people, using C#.NET. While I naturally wrote down something like:
`if (var_name == "some_text")`, one of the group members strongly insisted to change that line into `if ("some_text" == var_name)` and claim "it's a better programming practice" that she learned from some sensor programmer. No one in our group, not even herself, understood what's the motivation behind this besides it feels more awkward. Is this a better practice or it's just another urban myth?

Comment: in java doing `"some_text".equals(variable)` can prevent null pointer exceptions

Comment: In Java, doing a string comparison like: `"Something".equals(someVar)` won't throw a NullPointerException if `someVar` is null. I suppose it's faster than doing `someVar != null && someVar.equals("Something")`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no good reason for this **in C#**.

In C you can inadvertently forget one of the = signs, and C allows this:

`if (x = 5)`

Which will compile and always return either true or false (true if the variable was set to any non-zero value, false if it was zero).  This was a common source of errors, so writing `if (5 == x)` prevents this as the C compiler would complain if you ommitted one of the = signs.

C# however does NOT allow assignment to be treated as a boolean condition, and thus its impossible to make this mistake, so the suggestion is pointless.  I'd recommend sticking to the more natural "if x equals 5" style.

Comment: `if (x=5)` will return true in C because it's the same as `if (5)` because the assignment operator returns the result of the assignment. Everything that doesn't return zero will evaluate to false. So the following will return false: `if (x=0)`

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert Thanks, I've updated my answer to include your comment.

Comment: I never did this until I made this exact type and spent 6 hours debugging my code looking for the error. Now I **always** do it.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar You never did `if (5 == x)` until you had a bug?  In C/C++ yes, that's possible, but this question is about C# which won't even compile `if (x = 5)` .  It depends on the language you're in and the failsafes it has.  My answer that there isn't a good reason for `5 = x` is limited to C# / Vb.Net.

Comment: That's true, and a good deal of languages and IDEs will complain. I'm just saying that it's a habit I picked up after a bug in C++. It's the same reason I always refer to a field/property using `this`, because I screwed up in Java. It's not necessary, it's just a personal habit.

Comment: I don't find this as a good reason to lower readability by introducing hoopjumps like that.  To protect yourself from errors like `=`, there are tools like pre-commit hooks, `-Wall`, caution, asserts and much more.  What would your code look like if you tried to solve everything like that?

Comment: @AloisMahdal I wasn't advocating yoda conditions as a solution I was only stating WHY some people have decided to do that.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, I am not big fan of it.. But there is.. If you mistakenly would use operator assign (`=`) instead of compare it will not compile and/or it will immediately crash. At least in "common" programming languages ;-)

This web tells little bit more about it - http://united-coders.com/christian-harms/what-are-yoda-conditions/

Comment: An example being `'asd' = foo`.

Comment: This has been discussed many times but that's a good thing. I've heard it called "Yoda Comparisons" as in "asd is foo?" I got into the habit from my early C days where == and = were used together.

Comment: in C#, It won't compile neither "x"=foo nor foo="x"

Comment: I down voted because this question is specific to C#, and `if (x=5)` just won't compile there, so I don't agree with your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I started doing that in college when I took my first C++ class in an effort to not accidentally assign a value I was trying to check against, and it's just always followed me.  However, when I use C#, I tend to do:

```
if (var_name.Equals("some_text"))
```

Not only does this prevent the accidental assignment, but to me, visually, seeing the Equals() is much more understanding than seeing a ==.  Just my two cents.

Comment: Using `.Equals()` also allows you to specify the culture to be used for string comparison. This has become more important in recent years (decades?)

Answer (score 1):

I was taught to write it backwards when I was taking an intro to programming course in college. We were using C++, and as other answers said, it had a difference in C++.